# Select only databases with a certain table name and specific columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, join

So my first query is this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='logsys' and 
column_name in
('CD_LOG'
,'NM_USUARIO'
,'DT_ACAO'
,'DS_HISTORICO'
,'NOME_MAQUINA'
,'USUARIO_MAQUINA'
,'DATA_REFERENCIA'
,'ID_SISTEMA'
,'VERSAO'
,'LOCAL'
,'ACAO'
,'ID_LOG'
)
```

Then to run it in all databases, I made this:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 

   'use [?] SELECT 
   DB_NAME() as DatabaseName, * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name=''logsys'' and  column_name in
(''CD_LOG'',''NM_USUARIO'',''DT_ACAO'',''DS_HISTORICO'',''NOME_MAQUINA'',''USUARIO_MAQUINA'',''DATA_REFERENCIA''
,''ID_SISTEMA'',''VERSAO'',''LOCAL'',''ACAO'',''ID_LOG'')'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

But I'm just confused about something. I want THESE specific columns. I want tables with all these columns. not more, not less. but with `in`, obviously it lists tabes that have at least one of these columns. I'm confused about this simple query. How can I use it, in all databases, to find only those tables that has all those columns?

Should I use `and column = x, and column= y....` and so on?

And a bonus question. How can I insert `foreachdb` inside a table?

EDIT1:

Thanks for answers, for now, I have this:

```
--CRIA TABELA DO INSERT 
CREATE TABLE TB_DB_LOGSYS
    (
        DATABASENAME VARCHAR(200),
        TABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(200),
        TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(200),
        COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(200),
        DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(100)
    )
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
--PROCURA AS LOGSYS QUE POSSUEM 12 COLUNAS 
TRUNCATE TABLE TB_DB_LOGSYS
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 

   'use [?] SELECT 
   DB_NAME() as DatabaseName,  TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name=''logsys'' and  column_name in
(''CD_LOG'',''NM_USUARIO'',''DT_ACAO'',''DS_HISTORICO'',''NOME_MAQUINA'',''USUARIO_MAQUINA'',''DATA_REFERENCIA''
,''ID_SISTEMA'',''VERSAO'',''LOCAL'',''ACAO'',''ID_LOG'')'

--INSERE O FOREACHDB NA TABELA
INSERT INTO TB_DB_LOGSYS
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM TB_DB_LOGSYS

SELECT DATABASENAME, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS [COUNT] FROM TB_DB_LOGSYS
GROUP BY DATABASENAME
HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)=12
```

but using `having` is not what I really want. maybe there's another column, and not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: You're filtering by table name, how many `logsys` tables do you have?

Comment: Inside a database, there's only one logsys. But I think it could have more tables with those names.

Comment: then you should use `table_name like '%logsys%'`

Comment: Also try to avoid using sp_MSForEachDB for [many](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) reasons  - try an [alternative](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb).

Comment: After a time, you may find that having is not so pleasing a thing, after all, as wanting.  It is not logical... but it is often true.  Do you want now to search for a table that has only those columns and not any other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set up this sample on fiddle.uk just to show you one option.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE logsys_a(id int, v1 int, v2 int, v3 int, v4 int, v5 int);
> CREATE TABLE logsys_b(id int, v1 int, v2 int,         v4 int, v5 int);
> CREATE TABLE logsys_c(id int, v1 int, v2 int, v3 int, v4 int, v5 int);
> GO
> ```

1. Instead of use `USE [?]` you can use TABLE_CATALOG to filter on which database are you searching for. In my example I've used LIKE 'fiddle%' because it changes every time you executes the query.
2. You can check if `EXISTS` a table with all the required columns using HAVING COUNT() = x, as you can see in this case it only returns logsys_a and logsys_b.

As far as I don't know if you need all table columns I haven't used again `COLUMN_NAME IN ('v1','v2','v3','v4','v5')` on the main query.

> ```
> SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
> FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T1 
> WHERE  TABLE_CATALOG LIKE 'fiddle%'
> AND    TABLE_NAME LIKE '%logsys%'
> AND    EXISTS (SELECT   T2.TABLE_SCHEMA, T1.TABLE_NAME
>                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T2
>                WHERE    TABLE_CATALOG LIKE 'fiddle%'
>                AND      T2.TABLE_SCHEMA = T1.TABLE_SCHEMA
>                AND      T2.TABLE_NAME = T1.TABLE_NAME
>                AND      T2.COLUMN_NAME IN ('v1','v2','v3','v4','v5')
>                GROUP BY T2.TABLE_SCHEMA, T2.TABLE_NAME
>                HAVING COUNT(*) = 5);
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> TABLE_CATALOG                           | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME
> :-------------------------------------- | :----------- | :--------- | :----------
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_a   | id         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_a   | v1         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_a   | v2         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_a   | v3         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_a   | v4         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_a   | v5         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_c   | id         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_c   | v1         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_c   | v2         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_c   | v3         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_c   | v4         
> fiddle_a763285347ec46bb9b7fe95d5a6e754b | dbo          | logsys_c   | v5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=86cb263000a16f780b25e6c26eb2fba3)*

Comment: Nice, I used `having` in my query and it works great too. thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Give this one a try.  It returns all tables that have those specific columns you listed in it.  If it has more than those columns it will also be returned.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Tables') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##Tables 
END

CREATE TABLE ##Tables
    (
    DatabaseName SYSNAME NOT NULL
    , SchemaName SYSNAME NOT NULL
    , TableName SYSNAME NOT NULL
    )

DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SQLCommand = '
    USE [?];

    INSERT INTO ##Tables
    (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName)
    SELECT DB_NAME()
        , S.name AS SchemaName
        , T.name AS TableName
    FROM sys.schemas AS S
        INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T ON t.schema_id = S.schema_id
    WHERE T.object_id IN (
                        SELECT C.object_id
                            , COUNT(C.column_id) AS ColumnCount
                        FROM sys.columns AS C
                        WHERE C.name IN (''CD_LOG'',''NM_USUARIO'',''DT_ACAO'',''DS_HISTORICO'',''NOME_MAQUINA'',''USUARIO_MAQUINA'',''DATA_REFERENCIA''
                                        ,''ID_SISTEMA'',''VERSAO'',''LOCAL'',''ACAO'',''ID_LOG'')
                        GROUP BY C.object_id
                        HAVING COUNT(C.column_id) = 12
                        );
'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQLCommand;

SELECT DatabaseName
     , SchemaName
     , TableName 
FROM ##Tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can concat your columns and check on that.

This should do the trick

```
DECLARE @CMD VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result TABLE (DatabaseName varchar(200),TableName varchar(200), Column_Names varchar(max))

SET @CMD = 'use [?] 
DECLARE @TV table (DatabaseName varchar(200),TableName varchar(200),Column_Names varchar(max))
insert into @TV
select  DB_NAME() as DatabaseName,TABLE_NAME
        ,Column_Name = stuff((select '', '' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) as [text()]
        from information_schema.columns xt
        where xt.TABLE_NAME = t.Table_Name
        for xml path('''')), 1, 2, '''')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
group by TABLE_NAME
order by TABLE_NAME,Column_Name

select * from @TV
where 
Column_Names like ''%\[CD_LOG\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[NM_USUARIO\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[DT_ACAO\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[DS_HISTORICO\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[NOME_MAQUINA\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[USUARIO_MAQUINA\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[DATA_REFERENCIA\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[ID_SISTEMA\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[VERSAO\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[LOCAL\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[ACAO\]%'' ESCAPE ''\''
AND
Column_Names like ''%\[ID_LOG\]%'' ESCAPE ''\'''

insert into @Result
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @CMD

select * from @Result
```

You can use a Table Variable or temptable or physical table to store the result.

Comment: And what happens if he has a column with the name like "LOCAL-CUSTOMER"?

Comment: Column names get put together in long string. so it will be a string "blabla,ble,blabla,LOCAL-CUSTOMER"   and the LIKE is also a string where you can use - sign inside

Comment: Yes, but if I have an array such "LOCAL, BLAH, LOCAL-CUSTOMER" and I search for elements like %LOCAL% then I will get both LOCAL and LOCAL-CUSTOMER.

Comment: That is a fact, I'll add some brackets